# auth0 invite-only application JWT not appended at the end of redirect url

Tags: node.js, express, auth0

I'm following this [guide](https://auth0.com/docs/tutorials/creating-invite-only-applications), but at the user activation step after successful email verification, the jwt token was not appended as shown [here](https://auth0.com/docs/tutorials/creating-invite-only-applications#user-activation), but I got some other metadata instead:

`http://localhost:3000/onboarding?supportSignUp=true&supportForgotPassword=true&email=mail%40test.com&message=Your%20email%20was%20verified.%20You%20can%20continue%20using%20the%20application.&success=true#`

I'm using express and the auth0 nodejs api.

Comment: Have you disabled the default verification email sent by Auth0?
In the sample GitHub repo, this shows how to add the token to the URL: https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-invite-only-sample/blob/a78916291fc3181760c8ffb09bbed521f31abae2/Analystick/Areas/Admin/Controllers/UsersController.cs#L80-L87

Comment: @NicoSabena thanks for your input - the default verification email is disabled. I am a little confused about the code you linked since it's in C# and I work with a JS stack. 

I've set it up similar to the code where an email verification ticket is generated and sent to the user using sendgrid, that verification ticket has a `result_url` of http://localhost:3000/onboarding.

Are you saying that I have to take action to manually append the JWT token?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the generated JWT yourself in the `result_url`.

[This code](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-invite-only-sample/blob/a78916291fc3181760c8ffb09bbed521f31abae2/Analystick/Areas/Admin/Controllers/UsersController.cs#L80-L87) uses [API v2](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2#!/Tickets/post_email_verification) to create a new email verification ticket. It is specifying the `result_url` argument as the local `/Account/Activation` action handler. And it is putting the [generated JWT token](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-invite-only-sample/blob/a78916291fc3181760c8ffb09bbed521f31abae2/Analystick/Areas/Admin/Controllers/UsersController.cs#L75-L78) as part of the query string.

After the user verifies his o her email address (in Auth0), he will be redirected to the `result_url` endpoint, with the token in the query string (`/Account/Activation?userToken=xxxx` in the sample). [This piece of code](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-invite-only-sample/blob/a78916291fc3181760c8ffb09bbed521f31abae2/Analystick/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L39-L48) handles that endpoint, verifying the token received and showing a view that allows the user to enter his password and POST the final activation (handled [here](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-invite-only-sample/blob/a78916291fc3181760c8ffb09bbed521f31abae2/Analystick/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L50-L98)).

Comment: Thanks so much for your help Nico! I'm using RS256 and do not have access to the private key so I can't generate a JWT, changing to HS256 is not an option unfotunately. 

Any 'best practice' to handle this issue?